# How to connect to 2 live datasets in a report?

Tags: powerbi

I have a Power BI report and it allows me to get data using the import mode, direct query mode, live connect (to dataset) mode.

Also the recent feature allows me to convert the live connect mode to direct query mode so that I can combine live connect dataset with more data sources.

My goal is to connect my report to 2 live datasets in direct query mode. However, I am only able to connect to 1 live dataset in direct query mode and then get data from additional sources. Is connecting to 2 live datasets not supported?

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-composite-models#use-composite-models

> When you use DirectQuery, composite models make it possible to create
> a Power BI model, such as a single .pbix Power BI Desktop file, that
> does either or both of the following actions:
>
> Combines data from one or more DirectQuery sources. Combines data from
> DirectQuery sources and import data.

Comment: Is this question specifically related to connecting to two Power BI datasets at the same time? Because that is straightforward - just add a new data source and choose Power BI report. Perhaps you need premium capacity?

Comment: On my report, when I do a live connect to another Power BI dataset, it doesn't allow me to add any more data sources. Recently there is a new feature that needs enabling, and it then allows me to connect to other data sources when my report is already connected to another Power BI database (it converts the live connection into direct query). But it doesn't allow me to connect to another Power BI dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Ensure settings are correct. It is currently a preview feature to enable DQ for PBI datasets and AS:

[image]

Step 2: Add a new source, choose Power BI Dataset.

[image]

Step 3: Add another source, this will pop up. Choose to add a local model:

[image]

After another data set has been added, the storage mode is still DQ:

[image]

This was done on Version: `2.110.1161.0 64-bit`

Comment: When I make relationship between 2 models, then is the inner or left join?

Comment: The join depends on the relationship: `Many-many` is an inner join, `one-one` is a full outer join, `one-many` is a right outer join and `many-one` is a left outer join. See this relevant question: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Mapping-between-Join-type-and-cardinalities-in-PowerBI/m-p/813384

Comment: There is a concept of inter vs intra group relationships. For example no table expansion happens with inter group relationships. And by default inter group relationships are M:M. Do any such rules apply on relationships setup between direct query pbi datasets?

Comment: Great question! I do not know, but it should be straightforward to test. I have not heard these terms but after reading Power BI docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-relationships-understand#relationship-evaluation) I would assume that tables from different data sets would form «inter group» relationships, and that table expansion is not possible across these groups. If this is required functionality I would consider creating a new dataset that combine these two.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-relationships-understand#relationship-evaluation - `Note that relationships in import or DirectQuery models are always intra source group.` - this suggests it will be intra group.

Comment: But you are looking at a mixed/composite models with several sources: `Each source, including the Vertipaq cache of imported data, is considered to be a source group. Model relationships can then be classified as intra source group or inter/cross source group. ` In any event you can just test and see what is valid for your model.

Comment: Your point is valid but that quote conflicts with the quote from my last comment. Very confusing. How do I test this?

Comment: See example 1 here, using the many side table as a filter for a countrows of the one-side. https://blog.enterprisedna.co/expanded-tables-in-power-bi/

Comment: And how does that prove whether or not it does table expansion or whether it is inter/intra group?

Comment: Either the calculation is affected by table expansion or it is not. Only intra-group tables support table expansion - I thought this was your question?

Comment: Either ways the calculation will show the output. I can't think of how it will proove whether or not table expansion has occurred, and whether it was inter/intra.

Comment: Of course, but either it is filtered by expanded tables or it isn’t

Comment: No no it doesn't work like that. If not for table expansion then there is internal technique used to filter. So effectively the result is same. Table expansion is just more efficient.

Comment: I see, I learned something new then!